# Seam Custom Validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, jakarta-ee, seam

I'm trying to implement a custom validation annotation in Seam.

We have a list of objects, lets call it arrayA, and arrayA is different dependent on today's date.

Next we have an input field stringB, stringB is some value in arrayA going through a transformation function funcC(...).

So basically, we can validate stringB using the following loop:

```
for(a : arrayA)
{
    a.equals( funcC( stringB ) )
    return true
}
return false
```

My problem is, how do I do this in seam considering arrayA is dynamic? The seam/hibernate validation annotation seems to take only constants as input. Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always utilize Seam's `Component.getInstance()` from within your Validator to fetch the Array from your context. This assumes that you have populated a Seam-based Bean containing this array.

*For example:*

```
@Name("someValidator")
@Validator
public class SomeValidator implements javax.faces.validator.Validator {

  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    MyArrayBean bean = (MyArrayBean)Component.getInstance("myArrayBean");
    String[] arrayA = bean.getArray();

    for(String a : arrayA) {
      //etc
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternately**, if the Array can change depending on the page you are validating from; then you can always pass the value to the validator using `<f:attribute>`.

*For example:*

```
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.stringB}">
    <f:validator validatorId="someValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="arrayA" value="#{myArrayBean.array}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

And in your validator, in place of the `Component.getInstance()` you can load this array via the attribute:

```
String[] arrayA = component.getValueExpression("arrayA").getValue(context.getELContext());
```

[Note if passing the `String[]` doesn't work then pass in the Bean containing it instead.]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java Server Faces, the view technology used by Seam, **is a Server side based component technology**. If you have a **dynamic** Array property, so **i hope** you are updating the JSF Tree (you can use Ajax4JSF - default in RichFaces or ICEFaces).

As shown in your question, **you have a complex validation** (It involves more than on property and are dependent on processing of business logic). So the best place to put is inside your business logic. Think about it.

regards,